# I used keyframes because transition doesn't affect display property but now it doesn't Fade Out finely

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I used `keyframes` to apply animation while showing an element(Fade In & Fade Out). Because `transition` doesn't affect the `display` property. This is exactly what I mean ([Why Transition properties do not work with display properties? - GeeksforGeeks)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/why-transition-properties-does-not-work-with-display-properties/#:%7E:text=When%20we%20want%20to%20use,block%20cannot%20be%20partly%20displayed.)

But now I have another problem that the element Fades In finely but it doesn't Fade Out finely (It doesn't Fade Out when I scroll up after the button shows up.) This is what I mean (run the code.)

Thanks.

```js
// BTT icon show
const bttDisplay = () => {
    const backToTop = document.querySelector('.backToTop');
    const windowHeight = window.pageYOffset;

    if (windowHeight >= 500) {
        backToTop.style.bottom = '40px';
        backToTop.style.opacity = 1;
        backToTop.style.display = 'grid';
        backToTop.style.alignContent = 'center';
        backToTop.style.justifyItems = 'center';
    } else if (windowHeight <= 499) {
        backToTop.style.bottom = 0;
        backToTop.style.opacity = 0;
        backToTop.style.display = 'none';
    };
};

window.addEventListener('scroll', bttDisplay);

// Scroll back to top
const goUp = () => {
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
};

document.querySelector('.backToTop').addEventListener('click', goUp)
```

```css
@keyframes hover {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.bg {
    display: grid;
    justify-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    color: rgb(88, 102, 116);
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.bg1 {
    background-color: #ECB0F5;
}

.bg2 {
    background-color: #9EBFFF;
}

.bg3 {
    background-color: #54E694;
}

.bg4 {
    background-color: #FFFECC;
}

.bg5 {
    background-color: #F2DDC7;
}

.backToTop {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 25px;
    display: none;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -ms-border-radius: 50%;
    -o-border-radius: 50%;
    animation: hover 300ms;
}
```

```html
<section class="bg bg1">scroll</section>
<section class="bg bg2">down</section>
<section class="bg bg3">until to be</section>
<section class="bg bg4">able to</section>
<section class="bg bg5">return top</section>

<span class="backToTop">Top</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using CSS animations wrong. Animations by default only play once and you have manually control when they play using the animation-play-state property. Also you don't really need animations for this. A simple CSS transition works fine.

Try this code.

```js
// BTT icon show
const bttDisplay = () => {
    const backToTop = document.querySelector('.backToTop');
    const windowHeight = window.pageYOffset;
  
    if (windowHeight >= 500) {
        backToTop.style.bottom = '40px';
        backToTop.style.alignContent = 'center';
        backToTop.style.justifyItems = 'center';
        backToTop.style.display = 'grid';
        backToTop.style.opacity = "1";
    } else if (windowHeight <= 499) {
        backToTop.style.opacity = "0";
    };
};

window.addEventListener('scroll', bttDisplay);

// Scroll back to top
const goUp = () => {
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
};

document.querySelector('.backToTop').addEventListener('click', goUp)
```

```css
.bg {
    display: grid;
    justify-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    color: rgb(88, 102, 116);
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.bg1 {
    background-color: #ECB0F5;
}

.bg2 {
    background-color: #9EBFFF;
}

.bg3 {
    background-color: #54E694;
}

.bg4 {
    background-color: #FFFECC;
}

.bg5 {
    background-color: #F2DDC7;
}

.backToTop {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 25px;
    display: none;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<section class="bg bg1">scroll</section>
<section class="bg bg2">down</section>
<section class="bg bg3">until to be</section>
<section class="bg bg4">able to</section>
<section class="bg bg5">return top</section>

<span class="backToTop">Top</span>
```

Comment: This doesn't helped me and isn't what I want